# Can't get output shape of a keras layer inside a custom layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras custom layer built form multiple Keras layers. I am trying to get the output_shape of the inner layers form a callback (on_train_batch_end) and get the following error:
"AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape."

I don't understand how this can happen if the call function in the custom layer is called because I have already trained the model for a single batch.

a code example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  ReLU, MaxPooling2D, Input, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
        self.conv = None
        self.m_max = None
        self.relu = None

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.m_max(x)
        return self.relu(x)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv = Conv2D(input_shape=input_shape, filters=128, kernel_size=(2,2))
        self.m_max = MaxPooling2D()
        self.relu = ReLU()


class ModelCallback(Callback):
  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    print(self.model.layers[1].conv.output_shape)

inp = Input((32,32,3))
x = MyLayer()(inp)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy' )

x_train = np.random.rand(5000,32,32,3)
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(5000,1))

model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=5, callbacks=ModelCallback())
```

Comment: Tried reproducing your code but am facing the error, 
`NameError: name 'ds_train' is not defined`. Can you please provide the complete code (if it is not confidential) so that we can help you. Please find the Colab Gist:

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/cff6f829881fb99e39df3ec4a933b2be/so_68466828.ipynb

Comment: I updated the full code, this is just a dummy code I can share, but still got the same error.

Comment: @TFer2 , I created a new github gist with the correct code https://colab.research.google.com/gist/arielAmsel/fbb5f4d6bb6d615fec96c4a8d7d95ba5/so_68466828.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an answer but I will share my workaround for other people.
The idea is just to calculate the sizes on dummy data and save them.

```
def _calculate_shape(self, input_tensor_shape: tf.TensorShape):
    self.conv.trainable = False
    self.m_max.trainable = False
    self.relu.trainable = False
    input_shape = list(input_tensor_shape)
    input_shape[0] = self.batch_size
    x = self.conv(np.random.rand(*input_shape))
    self.conv_shapes = (input_shape[1:], tf.shape(x).numpy().tolist()[1:])     # [1:] is needed to remove the batch size form the shape
    x = self.m_max(x)
    self.max_shapes = (self.conv_shapes[1], tf.shape(x).numpy().tolist()[1:])
    x = self.relu(x)
    self.relu_shapes = (self.max_shapes[1], tf.shape(x).numpy().tolist()[1:])
    self.conv.trainable = True
    self.m_max.trainable = True
    self.relu.trainable = True
```

Then you can use the variables when trying to get the shape of inner layers.
** This removes the batch size from the shape